# simple flask app server passing data with ajax and jquery

Tags: python, jquery, html, ajax, flask

I've spent all day tinkering with this app trying to get some simple information passed to the back end of the application. I am using a simple flask app and trying to send data from a search query to the back end using ajax. However, I have been completely unsuccessful. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is app.py

```
from scraper import scrape
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, make_response, request
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():

    entries = json.dumps(scrape("video games"))
    return render_template('index.html', entries= entries)

@app.route('/parse_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_data():
    if request.method == "GET":
        #data = request.form("blah")
        #print("blah")
        search = request.json
        #new_search = json.dumps(scrape(data))
        return search
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

and index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Flask app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  </head>
<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <form name = "textbox" id = "textbox">
      <input id ="textbox" name="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
      <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <p>you searched: {{search}} </p>

  <div id="div1">
  <p id="p1"></p>
  <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>

<script>

var value = $('.textbox').val();
//alert(value);
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/parse_data",
  data: JSON.stringify(value)
  contentType: 'application/json',
  success: function(data){
    alert("success")
  }
});



var jsonz = {{ entries|tojson }};



var s = JSON.parse(jsonz);



var i;
for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
  var para = document.createElement("p");
  var node = document.createTextNode(s[i].product_name + "\n" + s[i].product_link);
  para.appendChild(node);

  var element = document.getElementById("div1");
  element.appendChild(para);
}




//document.getElementById("user").innerHTML =
//obj;
//"Name: " + obj.product_name + "<br>" +
//"Location: " + obj.product_link;
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet has a few issues, mostly:

- Your AJAX request is not bind to the button click event, so clicking the button does nothing.
- You have two html elements with the same id `textbox`, id are supposed to be unique.
- To get an html element by id use `"#textbox"`

On the server side (Flask):

- Use the function `get_json()` of the request
- To process the `POST` request you need to check for `POST` not `GET`

Try wrapping your POST request like this:

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = $("#textbox").val();
    alert(value);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "parse_data",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "text" : value } ),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    });

});
```

Also remove the duplicate ids `textbox`, change the id of the form to something like `textbox-form`, finally change your `parse_data` function to something like this:

```
@app.route('/parse_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_data():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.get_json()
        return jsonify(search)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Comment: I changed the code to what you have. It works now. Could you explain what I was mostly doing wrong?

Comment: Masejo Thank you so much I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @ Daniel Mesejo One last question: how does it know what button I click?

Comment: $("button").click means select the button objects and add the function as a callback, as you only have one button object it only applies to that one if you had more than one you will have to use a more specific selector, pointing to the id or class like $("#mybutton").

Comment: Thank you for the info. Can I ask one more? I can't seem to get the search to render on the template. In other words: when I post with a search query, nothing gets returned to the template and displayed like I would want. Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with the new example and problem. I'll be glad to answer!

Comment: Masejo OK here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51922105/passing-a-variable-from-the-backend-to-the-frontend-in-a-flask-app