# check for value change in dataframe using flask app

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

with this code, I am checking if the value in the column `check_val` is true or not,
and create list of `Ticker` to render on html webpage.

as the values in `check_val` column changes frequently,  to make sure that correct list
is rendered, i call this endpoint every 10 seconds using following line in html file

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

.

```
@app.route('/check')
def check():
    filename = r'C:\Users\91956\Desktop\Book.xlsm'
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)

    df = df.loc[df['check_val'] == True]
    ticker_list = df['Ticker'].to_list()
 

    return render_template('layout.html',lis = ticker_list)
```

this causes refresh of page every 10 seconds.
is there any other alterative to accomplish this, **without** refreshing the page?

Comment: Have you considered using javascript to update just the table every 10 seconds instead of the whole page?

Comment: as the dataframe is created using excel file, while updating table i need to access excel file, how to do this using javascript

Comment: You don't need to refresh the page. You should send request via javascript. You use plain HTML?

Comment: Javascript doesn't access your excel file, javscript asks your server for the updated data. It is the function of your server to access your excel file and format it for javascipt to understand.

Comment: It's a lot resources out there... try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51913220/simple-flask-app-server-passing-data-with-ajax-and-jquery